# Navigation Duplicated when pushing new query to vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I push query to router by the following command

```
this.$router.push({ query: { queryKey: ["a", "b", "c"] } });
```

Each click on element pushes new value to array, so first query is “a”, then [“a”, “b”], then [“a”, “b”, “c”]. And that’s where I start having problem. First and second queries are ok, but third one despite being different from the second one is regarded as duplicate by vue router.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Check the routing history in Vue DevTools.

Comment: New entry is not added to routing history as the navigation doesn't happen, it gets blocked as if I navigate to the same fullPath.

Comment: Can you add a `beforeEach` hook which will log FROM and TO in the console ?

Comment: When I navigate from ?key=val to ?key=val&key=val2 in FROM and TO I see those values in router, router navigates from fullPath /?key=val to fullPath ?key=val&key=val2. When I want to go to next query, ?key=val&key=val2&key=val3 I don't see anything besides NavigationDuplicated error in console. BeforeEach hook gets blocked as well.

Answer (score 1):

That was my mistake. I was manipulating a variable to which I assigned this.$route.query.key. So besides pushing to my variable I was mutating the original array from this.$route.query in background without thinking about it.